# Summarize based on conditions in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sql table transactions, with the following form:

```
amount date
1000    2020-01-05
-10     2020-01-13
-75     2020-01-19
-7      2020-01-25
2000    20202-03-10
-10     2020-03-12
...
```

I want to sum all the amounts of the amount column, and I have to add a -5 for every months I do not have mininum 3 amounts with "-" and the total of the minus are <= -100. How can I do that calculation. For the start I did:

```
SELECT date(date, 'start of month')
 ,   count(amount), sum(amount)
from transactions
--condition that it only counts the negative amounts (that are the credit card payments)
where amount <0
group by 
    date(date, 'start of month')
```

which retunrs a table:

```
2020-01 3 -93
2020-03 1 -10
```

so in that case both months did not reach the condition and it would produce a -5 on top for that month

so the outcome would be:

```
balance
2888
```

Comment: *I have to add a -5 for every months I do not have mininum 3 amounts with "-" and the total of the minus are >= 100* For your sample data in `2020-01` there are 3 negative amounts and their total is -92 (not -93) Why did you add -5?

Comment: sorry, I have to add -5, because the total was not <= -100

Comment: the idea is that I have a penalty balance fee, if i did not spend more then -100 in a month

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUM()` window function and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       SUM(
         SUM(amount) - 
         CASE 
           WHEN TOTAL(amount < 0) < 3 
             OR TOTAL(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END) >= -100 
           THEN 5 
           ELSE 0 
         END
       ) OVER () AS total
FROM transactions
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', date);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z82uR6uE).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exec.sql", line 89, in <module>
    writer(args[2], result)
  File "exec.sql", line 39, in writer
    f.write("%d\n" % len(res))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: @PV8 this is an error coming from your Python code. My answer is about the SQLite query that you need. You can see in the demo I provide in my answer that the query is syntactically correct.